# TestApplication in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor, koin

So i have built my Ktor backend and im watching a tutorial from philip lackner [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufoTXJ0eRQY&list=PLQkwcJG4YTCQDFGWBnwIFnOdfp4CDRB-Z&index=10)
He starts of with making a withTestApplication call within his testfunction... The thing is that this has been deprecated and it would be nice to use the newer version of it which i understand is

```
@Test
fun `Create user, no body attached, responds with BadRequest`() = testApplication{
   application {
       install(Routing) {
           createUserRoute(userRepository)
       }
   }
}
```

And so i use this code but i have no clue how to get the scope so i can use handleRequest?
please can somebody help me with this?

This is the code i wanted to test

```
package com.PapperSeller.routes

import com.PapperSeller.controller.user.UserRepository
import com.PapperSeller.data.models.User
import com.PapperSeller.data.requests.CreateAccountRequest
import com.PapperSeller.data.responses.BasicApiResponse
import com.PapperSeller.util.ApiResponseMessages
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import org.koin.ktor.ext.inject


fun Route.createUserRoute(repository: UserRepository){

    route("/api/user/create"){
        post {
            kotlin.runCatching { call.receive<CreateAccountRequest>()}.onSuccess {request ->
                val userExist = repository.getUserByEmail(request.email) != null
                if(userExist){
                    call.respond(BasicApiResponse(ApiResponseMessages.USER_ALREADY_EXIST, false))
                    return@post
                }else{
                    if(request.email.isBlank() || request.username.isBlank() || request.password.isBlank()){
                        call.respond(BasicApiResponse(ApiResponseMessages.FIELDS_EMPTY, false))
                        return@post
                    }else{
                        repository.createUser(User(email = request.email, username = request.username, password = request.password))
                        call.respond(BasicApiResponse("", true))
                        return@post
                    }
                }

            }.onFailure {
                call.respond(BasicApiResponse(ApiResponseMessages.NO_USER_REGISTERED, false))
                return@post


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Within the `testApplication` you can use an `HttpClient` instance to make requests to a test server. Here is the docs https://ktor.io/docs/testing.html.

Comment: He uses handlerequest which is not available in that scope what i can see... is there another way to do the same thing please give an example

Comment: To give an example, please describe the functionality of a server that needs to be covered with a test.

Comment: okey just such a simple function as registering a user and testing the response of your route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can cover the `Route.createUserRoute` with tests:

```
import io.ktor.client.call.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.testing.*
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class KtorTest {
    @Test
    fun userNotRegistered() = testApplication {
        application {
            module(MemoryUserRepository())
        }

        val client = createClient {
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                json()
            }
        }

        assertEquals(
            BasicApiResponse(ApiResponseMessages.NO_USER_REGISTERED, false),
            client.post("/api/user/create").body()
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun userAlreadyExist() = testApplication {
        application {
            module(MemoryUserRepository(mapOf("john@doe" to User("", "", ""))))
        }

        val client = createClient {
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                json()
            }
        }

        client.post("/api/user/create") {
            setBody(CreateAccountRequest("john@doe", "", ""))
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        }.body<BasicApiResponse>().let { response ->
            assertEquals(BasicApiResponse(ApiResponseMessages.USER_ALREADY_EXIST, false), response)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun emptyRequestFields() = testApplication {
        application {
            module(MemoryUserRepository())
        }

        val client = createClient {
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                json()
            }
        }

        client.post("/api/user/create") {
            setBody(CreateAccountRequest("", "", ""))
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        }.body<BasicApiResponse>().let { response ->
            assertEquals(BasicApiResponse(ApiResponseMessages.FIELDS_EMPTY, false), response)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun successfulRegistration() = testApplication {
        application {
            module(MemoryUserRepository())
        }

        val client = createClient {
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                json()
            }
        }

        client.post("/api/user/create") {
            setBody(CreateAccountRequest("john@doe", "john", "123"))
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        }.body<BasicApiResponse>().let { response ->
            assertEquals(BasicApiResponse("", true), response)
        }
    }
}

fun Application.module(repository: UserRepository) {
    install(io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }
    routing {
        createUserRoute(repository)
    }
}

fun Route.createUserRoute(repository: UserRepository) {
    route("/api/user/create") {
        post {
            kotlin.runCatching { call.receive<CreateAccountRequest>() }.onSuccess { request ->
                val userExist = repository.getUserByEmail(request.email) != null
                if (userExist) {
                    call.respond(BasicApiResponse(ApiResponseMessages.USER_ALREADY_EXIST, false))
                    return@post
                } else {
                    if (request.email.isBlank() || request.username.isBlank() || request.password.isBlank()) {
                        call.respond(BasicApiResponse(ApiResponseMessages.FIELDS_EMPTY, false))
                        return@post
                    } else {
                        repository.createUser(
                            User(
                                email = request.email,
                                username = request.username,
                                password = request.password
                            )
                        )
                        call.respond(BasicApiResponse("", true))
                        return@post
                    }
                }
            }.onFailure {
                call.respond(BasicApiResponse(ApiResponseMessages.NO_USER_REGISTERED, false))
                return@post
            }
        }
    }
}

class ApiResponseMessages {
    companion object {
        val USER_ALREADY_EXIST = "User does already exist"
        val FIELDS_EMPTY = "Something missing"
        val NO_USER_REGISTERED = "User isn't registered"
    }
}

interface UserRepository {
    fun getUserByEmail(email: String): User?
    fun createUser(user: User)
}

class MemoryUserRepository(initialUsers: Map<String, User> = mapOf()): UserRepository {
    private val users = initialUsers.toMutableMap()

    override fun getUserByEmail(email: String): User? {
        return users[email]
    }

    override fun createUser(user: User) {
        users[user.email] = user
    }
}

@Serializable
data class CreateAccountRequest(val email: String, val username: String, val password: String)

data class User(val email: String, val username: String, val password: String)

@Serializable
data class BasicApiResponse(val message: String, val success: Boolean)
```

Comment: Take a look at the tutorial i have sent in my main question he starts dealing with this kind of test at 24:38 and i basically want to do the same thing as he does there must be a way to do the same but with updated code?

Comment: Please describe in your own words what functionality should be covered with a test.

Comment: HAve done so in my main question

Comment: 'fun <P : Pipeline<*, ApplicationCall>, B : Any, F : Any> install(plugin: Plugin<ApplicationCallPipeline, ContentNegotiationConfig, PluginInstance>, configure: ContentNegotiationConfig.() -> Unit = ...): Unit' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary i get this as an error trying this out

Comment: Make sure that you imported the `ContentNegotiation` plugin from `io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation` for the test client and `io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation` for the server respectively.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman insane perfect comment. But why this is not to clear in the Ktor docs? I felt it was not very clarified when I was reading and learning from official site and this basic difference make spent hours trying to know why my test wrote exactly as the examples doesn't works or even compiles.